# Using conditional list as module option?

Tags: ansible

I recently discovered, that the package module can take a package lists directly to its `name` option. This speeds up the package installation process a lot, as all packages are installed in one call to yum/apt.

Conciser the following variable:

```
managed_packages:
  - name: bind-utils
    os_family: RedHat
    state: present
  - name: curl
    state: present
  - name: dnsutils
    os_family: Debian
    state: present
```

And the corresponding task:

```
- name: manage packages
  package:
    name: "{{item.name}}"
    state: "{{item.state}}"
  with_items: "{{managed_packages}}"
  when: "'os_family' not in item or item.os_family == ansible_os_family"
```

I'm searching for a way to utilize this feature in this task.
Anyone an idea, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved with the [json_query() filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter).

```
- name: manage packages
  package:
    name: "{{ managed_packages | json_query('[?(state==`' + item + '`) && (!os_family || os_family==`' + ansible_os_family + '`)].name') }}"
    state: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - present
    - absent
```